# mod_evasive : White-listing causing to not having Access Logs?

Tags: apache-httpd, logs, mod-evasive

I'm using `mod_evasive` with Apache. And there is an directive to whitelist the IP(s). Like:

```
DOSWhitelist 127.0.0.1
DOSWhitelist 10.0.*.*
DOSWhitelist 100.200.*.*
```

This is fine because we need to whitelist some of our own IPs. But the problem is:

- after i did this white-listing, my Apache is totally not saving any `access_log` for that IPs anymore.
- the `access_log` got totally no records for that IPs anymore.

Is this happening to everyone? I was expecting the `mod_evasive` **to be just white-listing only** (a.k.a: not to block those IPs) -- but not to let Apache totally hands off from those IPs. (Of course i still need access logs!)

Is this a known trade-off of using `mod_evasive`?
Any idea please?